# Docker compose throws - adduser: group 'www-data' in use

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-composer.yml` file which used to work just fine a couple of months ago, but now when I run it throws an error.

First, this is my file structure.

```
.data/db
logs
mariadb
nginx
php7-fpm
src/public
.env
.gitignore
README
docker-compose.yml
```

The only mention of the error i.e `www-data` is in two of the files. `php7-fpm/Dockerfile` and `nginx/Dockerfile`

Here is the content of these files:

php-fpm/Dockerfile

```
....
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www


nginx/Dockerfile

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY ./sites /etc/nginx/sites-available
RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --no-cache bash \
    && adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data

ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000

# Set upstream conf and remove the default conf
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server     ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
&& rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file is a generic one, there is no tampering with user groups, but here is a pastebin for anyone who wants to take a look.

https://pastebin.com/ivRfPvZz

This is the partial output from the `docker-compose up -d` command.

```sh
Image for service php-fpm was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Building nginx
Step 1/8 : FROM nginx:alpine
alpine: Pulling from library/nginx
Digest: sha256:17bd1698318e9c0f9ba2c5ed49f53d690684dab7fe3e8019b855c352528d57be
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:alpine
 ---> ea1193fd3dde
Step 2/8 : COPY ./config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
 ---> 65c115482d37
Step 3/8 : COPY ./sites /etc/nginx/sites-available
 ---> 1fbe81620355
Step 4/8 : RUN apk update     && apk upgrade     && apk add --no-cache bash     && adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data
 ---> Running in c631ccdf63f2
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.9.4-61-g22a1991b6a [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main]
v3.9.4-57-gb40ea6190b [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community]
OK: 9776 distinct packages available
(1/1) Upgrading libbz2 (1.0.6-r6 -> 1.0.6-r7)
OK: 27 MiB in 37 packages
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/2) Installing readline (7.0.003-r1)
(2/2) Installing bash (4.4.19-r1)
Executing bash-4.4.19-r1.post-install
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 29 MiB in 39 packages
adduser: group 'www-data' in use
Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update     && apk upgrade     && apk add --no-cache bash     && adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

You can see the error is:

```
adduser: group 'www-data' in use
Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk update     && apk upgrade     && apk add --no-cache bash     && adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

but I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx), when you use `FROM nginx:alpine`, in fact it sames with using `nginx:1.17.1-alpine` because they are just different tags for same image id.

But several month ago, when you use `nginx:alpine`, `latest` maybe others, E.g. `nginx:1.14.2-alpine`, so when rebuild using the same dockerfile, the base image indeed changed. I strongly suggest you use an explicit tag not latest as base image to assure definiteness.

Finally, what happened for several month ago?

1. Use `nginx:1.14.2-alpine`, maybe not this version, just an example：

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -it nginx:1.14.2-alpine cat /etc/group | grep www-data
   ```

   You can see there is no `www-data` group in the image, so you can use next to add a new user also a new group with the name `www-data`:

   ```
   adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data
   ```
2. Use `nginx:1.17.1-alpine`, which currently same as `nginx:alpine`:

   ```
   $ docker run --rm -it nginx:1.17.1-alpine cat /etc/group | grep www-data
   www-data:x:82:
   ```

   You can see there is a default `www-data` group in this image, don't know how it generates, in a word, the image update bring something difference.

   So, as already a `www-data` group there, what you have to do is change your command to next to join a existed group:

   ```
   adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data -G www-data
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much. Can I ask you something? why did you say you strongly suggest I use specific tag instead of latest, if your last solution adds a users to an already existing group? It seems to me like that is the best alternative because you can always install the latest while being sure adding the user to an existing group will avoid the error. In short, you get a latest version and a working user group at the same time while a specific tag means you have to up the version with every new release.

Comment: If use latest, this time you had the `adduser: group 'www-data' in use` issue, next time, you may encountered other issue. Suppose you are a `devops` engineer who also work on operation, then one day if you need to redeploy the service, you may find it not work because the `latest` already changed, you may need hours to find what happened & fix it. But, you customer is waiting for you, you boss is waiting for you... Anyway, this just a practice, use latest also could be accept if you could manage it well. And, if you are a pure development engineer, I guess you will not care that...

Answer (score 6):

You can find the DockerFile inside laradock/nginx folder. Just change the line

```
&& adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data
```

to

```
&& adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data -G www-data
```

This specifies the group that the user is a member of. Once done, build and bring your containers up with

```
docker-compose build --no-cache nginx
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this issue with Alpine 3.14, where the `www-data` group already exists in the image.

Adding `(delgroup www-data || true)` before the line with `adduser` in it will fix the problem.

```
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& (delgroup www-data || true) \
&& adduser -D -H -u 1000 -s /bin/bash www-data
```

The parentheses with the `|| true` will ensure that the command won't fail if the group does not exist, so it is backward compatible.